# Calling a function that's defined inside a function

Tags: javascript, function

*Is there a way to call a function defined inside another function in javaSCRIPT? For example:

```
window.onload() = function() {
    function my_function(){
        print("Blah");
    };
};

function function_two(){
    my_function();
};
```

Is there a way to do something like the above (calling my_function in function_two even though it's defined inside the window.onload() function)? In my actual code, which also uses the raphael.js library, I'm trying to write a button in HTML, which using the onClick function, calls a function(like function_two) that runs the function defined in window.onload() (like my_function). However the console says that the my_function is undefined.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The scope of the function is the core issue here, as Zeychin and Trevor have said. I thought I'd offer another way of handling it. Basically, you can set your function to a variable that's in a higher scope (that is, accessible to both the onload and function_two functions), while defining it inside the onload function as you originally have:

```
var myFunction; //This is the placeholder which sets the scope

window.onload() = function() {
   myFunction = function() { //Assign the function to the myFunction variable
      print('blah');
   }
}

function function_two() {
   myFunction();
}
```

This might be handy if you only know the information you need for myFunction once you're in the onload event.

Comment: I could not make this example work. It says "JavaScript error: Uncaught TypeError: Property 'myFunction' of object [object Object] is not a function"

Comment: Rodrigo - that error suggests you're calling 'myFunction' as a property/method of another object. Can you ask another question or post the code as a JSfiddle?

Comment: Also, Rodrigo, downvoting an answer in this situation isn't what downvotes are for ... particularly if you want help with your specific problem. Take a look at this (and others like it): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers

Comment: The code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/zEAWk/
It says "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment", probably because of the "()" after "window.onload". I also tried to change "print('blah') to "alert('blah')", but was still not able to run.

Answer (score 3):

```
window.onload = function() {
    my_function()
};

function my_function(){
    alert("Blah");
};

function function_two(){
    my_function();
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can not do what you are asking to do.
The function `my_function()`'s scope is only within the anonymous function, `function()`. It falls out of scope when the method is not executing, so this is not possible.
Trevor's answer is the way to do this.