# Run a function defined inside a Promise.then()

Tags: javascript, function, button, nested

I have a function to read a file which returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```js
const fetchFile = async () => {
    let res = await fetch('myfile.json');
    let feat = await res.json();
    return fileContent;
}
```

Then, I run some code only when the promise has been resolved (i.e. when the actual file content has been loaded) using [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then):

```js
var external_variable = 2
fetchFile().then(fileContent => { 
    // do many things with fileContent and external_variable
    const myFunction = (fileContent[0].properties) => {
        // do stuff with some properties of the json object contained in the file
        // which has been loaded and external_variable
    }
    // do other things
});
```

But when I try to call `myFunction` using a button on my HTML page:

```html
<button id ="myButton1" onclick="myFunction()">The do stuff button</button>
```

I'm facing this error: `Uncaught TypeError: myFunction is not a function`

Hence my question; how can I call this function when I click on my button?

These doesn't help much:
[promise.then functions only works if defined inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61078745/promise-then-functions-only-works-if-defined-inside)
[Calling a function that's defined inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784079/calling-a-function-thats-defined-inside-a-function)
[How does Promise run when .then method is not called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51431235/how-does-promise-run-when-then-method-is-not-called)
[Javascript call nested function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817872/javascript-call-nested-function)

Comment: [This answer to "Calling a function that's defined inside a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6784098/215552) should work in this case.

Comment: As mentioned by others, this is a scope problem. You also have a typo `myFnction`

Comment: Typo fixed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inline handlers [may only reference global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045) (and should never be used in modern code anyway, they have way too many problems to be used anyway).

Since you only define `myFunction` after the `fetchFile` resolves, add a listener to the button with `addEventListener` at that point, and remove the inline handler:

```
var external_variable = 2
fetchFile().then(fileContent => { 
    // do many things with fileContent and external_variable
    const myFunction = () => {
        // do stuff with some properties of the json object contained in the file
        // which has been loaded and external_variable
    };
    document.querySelector('#myButton1').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
    // do other things
});
```

Comment: Possibly also add an event listener in the default case (before the promise fulfills) that alerts "file is still loading, try again" and another event listener in a `catch` that alerts an error message, so that the button is not dead if clicked too early or when something failed.